# Julian date issue

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT TOP(3)  
  DATEADD(DAY, PRRCDJ % 1000, DATEADD(YEAR, PRRCDJ / 1000, -1))
FROM Table_name
```

the above SQL query converts the Julian date into normal date format.
But the issue here is when PRRCDJ have value 0.0 then it converts values into "1899-12-31 00:00:00.0".

Comment: What did you expect 0.0 to return ?

Comment: It should return blank field .

Answer (score 0):

This will null if the value of PRRCDJ is less than 1:

```
SELECT TOP(3)  
  CASE WHEN PRRCDJ >= 1 
       THEN DATEADD(DAY, PRRCDJ % 1000, DATEADD(YEAR, PRRCDJ / 1000, -1)) 
  END
FROM Table_name
```

Comment: @PeterSmith no ELSE is needed, this will return NULL just fine without, Rolled back your change.

Comment: Understood, just wanted to present an alternate way of returning a value